# Odd outlet identification

Tags: receptacle

I have a house in the USA from the 1940s/1950s and there is a strange outlet that I am unfamiliar with. A Google image search did not help.

Can anyone identify it? I'm trying to find a plate/cover for it.

[image]

EDIT: It seems to be a phone jack, but there are no wires in it that helps identify it. I saw similar brackets and oval shaped phone outlets, but not with the circular hole like this one:
[image]

I did think this was the answer. The bracket and shape is spot on; I just thought the hole was a broken area in the middle, but Jack's answer cleared it up.

Comment: Are there wires behind it? How are they attached? What does the back look like? Could it be for a (likely neon bulb) indicator lamp for something?

Comment: Just wondering if it would be closer to a speaker type jack, than an electrical outlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a vintage Western Electric phone jack. They were used before the bulky four prong plugs when people usually only had one phone in the house and it was hard wired. A heavy phone cord, the same color as the phone, was put through this jack and the connections were made on the back of it along with a crimped connector fastened to the jack to prevent the phone wire from pulling out.
See picture below from Ebay.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/155607005278?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&srsltid=ASuE1wT3na1MUoAqOHggInQB2q7qeY6uxZw1LcZP8Dso26nFDEZfB5AeM2o

[image]

Showing my age. :-)

Comment: Is that the kind of phone where you had a party line? :-D

Comment: Great detective work!

Comment: @Huesmann  Exactly... and the phone company would install only one outlet per phone.

Comment: @MTA  not really detective work... just old age.  I used to swap these out for the 4 prong plugs and the clip ins  we use today.

Comment: Well, 23-skidoo, Daddy-o!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a ground connector for a radio. Old-time tube radios needed an antenna and a good ground in order to work. The antenna was often built into the radio but ground had to come from somewhere. A cast iron radiator or a water pipe sometimes served as a ground, but a banana plug connector in the wall was more genteel.